# Groovy Missing Property Exception

Tags: jenkins, groovy, changeset

I have a jenkins build that needs to get the filenames for all files checked in within a changeset.

I have installed groovy on the slave computer and configured Jenkins to use it. I am running the below script that should return the names (or so I assume as this may be wrong as well) and print to the console screen however I am getting this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: paths for class: hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet
```

Here is the Groovy System Script:

```
import hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet

// work with current build
def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable

// get ChangesSets with all changed items
def changeSet= build.getChangeSet()
def items = changeSet.getItems()
def affectedFiles = items.collect { it.paths }

// get file names
def fileNames = affectedFiles.flatten().findResults
fileNames.each {
    println "Item: $it" // `it` is an implicit parameter corresponding to the current element
}
```

I am very new to Groovy and Jenkins so if its syntax issue or if I'm missing a step please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the version of `jenkins` you are using but according to the sourcecode of `ChangeSet` that you can find [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins/tfs/1.2/hudson/plugins/tfs/model/ChangeSet.java#ChangeSet.getAffectedPaths%28%29) I suggest you to replace line `9` with:

```
 def affectedFiles = items.collect { it.getAffectedPaths() }
 // or with the equivalent more groovy-idiomatic version
 def affectedFiles = items.collect { it.affectedPaths }
```

Feel free to comment the answer if there will be more issues.

Comment: That fixed my first issue! Thank you! Now I am running into an issue with the .findResults on line 12.  Really I just need the filename. I removed findResults and got the entire path to the file.  Any idea how to just return the filename?

Comment: @NicolePhillips: this actually would have required a new question but blindly try something like `def filenames = affectedFiles.flatten().findResults { it.replaceFirst('.*/','') }`